# Dotted filled line with arrow head in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

How can I get a dotted line around the arrow heads in the following arrow style?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{dotArrow} = [
  draw=blue, dotted, line width=0.6pt, double distance=4pt,
  {Bar[width=5.2pt]}-{Triangle[angle=90:7.2pt, fill=white]},
  postaction={draw=white, solid, line width=4pt, shorten >=4pt, shorten <=0.6pt, -}]

\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=5pt]
  \node[draw] (node1) {Node 1};
  \node[draw, right=of node1] (node2) {Node 2};
  \draw[dotArrow] (node1) -- (node2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `arrows.meta` library, the dash pattern is switched off by the `\pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}` command. What you can to is to copy the style, change the name, and modify the dash pattern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name = Dashed Stealth,
  defaults = {
    length  = +3pt 4.5 .8,
    width'  = +0pt .75,
    inset'  = +0pt 0.325,
    line width = +0pt 1 1,
  },
  setup code = {
    % Cap the line width at 1/4th distance from inset to tip
    \pgf@x\pgfarrowlength
    \advance\pgf@x by-\pgfarrowinset
    \pgf@x.25\pgf@x
    \ifdim\pgf@x<\pgfarrowlinewidth
      \pgfarrowlinewidth\pgf@x
    \fi
    % Compute front miter length:
    \pgfmathdivide@{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgfarrowlength}{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgfarrowwidth}%
    \let\pgf@temp@quot\pgfmathresult%
    \pgf@x\pgfmathresult pt%
    \pgf@x\pgfmathresult\pgf@x%
    \pgf@x4\pgf@x%
    \advance\pgf@x by1pt%
    \pgfmathsqrt@{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@x}%
    \pgf@xc\pgfmathresult\pgfarrowlinewidth% xc is front miter
    \pgf@xc.5\pgf@xc
    \pgf@xa\pgf@temp@quot\pgfarrowlinewidth% xa is extra harpoon miter
    % Compute back miter length:
    \pgf@ya.5\pgfarrowwidth%
    \csname pgfmathatan2@\endcsname{\pgfmath@tonumber\pgfarrowlength}{\pgfmath@tonumber\pgf@ya}%
    \pgf@yb\pgfmathresult pt%
    \csname pgfmathatan2@\endcsname{\pgfmath@tonumber\pgfarrowinset}{\pgfmath@tonumber\pgf@ya}%
    \pgf@ya\pgfmathresult pt%
    \advance\pgf@yb by-\pgf@ya%
    \pgf@yb.5\pgf@yb% half angle in yb
    \pgfmathtan@{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@yb}%
    \pgfmathreciprocal@{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgf@yc\pgfmathresult\pgfarrowlinewidth%
    \pgf@yc.5\pgf@yc%
    \advance\pgf@ya by\pgf@yb%
    \pgfmathsincos@{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@ya}%
    \pgf@ya\pgfmathresulty\pgf@yc% ya is the back miter
    \pgf@yb\pgfmathresultx\pgf@yc% yb is the top miter
    \ifdim\pgfarrowinset=0pt%
      \pgf@ya.5\pgfarrowlinewidth% easy: back miter is half linewidth
    \fi
    % Compute inset miter length:
    \pgfmathdivide@{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgfarrowinset}{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgfarrowwidth}%
    \let\pgf@temp@quot\pgfmathresult%
    \pgf@x\pgfmathresult pt%
    \pgf@x\pgfmathresult\pgf@x%
    \pgf@x4\pgf@x%
    \advance\pgf@x by1pt%
    \pgfmathsqrt@{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@x}%
    \pgf@yc\pgfmathresult\pgfarrowlinewidth% yc is inset miter
    \pgf@yc.5\pgf@yc% 
    % Inner length (pgfutil@tempdima) is now arrowlength - front miter - back miter
    \pgfutil@tempdima\pgfarrowlength%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-\pgf@xc%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-\pgf@ya%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb.5\pgfarrowwidth%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by-\pgf@yb%
    % harpoon miter correction
    \ifpgfarrowroundjoin
      \pgfarrowssetbackend{\pgf@ya\advance\pgf@x by-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}    
    \else
      \pgfarrowssetbackend{0pt}
    \fi
    \ifpgfarrowharpoon
      \pgfarrowssetlineend{\pgfarrowinset\advance\pgf@x
        by\pgf@yc\advance\pgf@x by.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}
    \else
      \pgfarrowssetlineend{\pgfarrowinset\advance\pgf@x by\pgf@yc\advance\pgf@x by-.25\pgfarrowlinewidth}
      \ifpgfarrowreversed
        \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt
          \pgfarrowssetlineend{\pgfarrowinset}
        \else
          \pgfarrowssetlineend{\pgfutil@tempdima\advance\pgf@x by\pgf@ya\advance\pgf@x by-.25\pgfarrowlinewidth}
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
    \ifpgfarrowroundjoin
      \pgfarrowssettipend{\pgfutil@tempdima\advance\pgf@x by\pgf@ya\advance\pgf@x by.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}    
    \else
      \pgfarrowssettipend{\pgfarrowlength\ifpgfarrowharpoon\advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa\fi}
    \fi
    % The hull:
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{\pgfarrowlength\ifpgfarrowroundjoin\else\ifpgfarrowharpoon\advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa\fi\fi}{\ifpgfarrowharpoon-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth\else0pt\fi}%
    \pgfarrowsupperhullpoint{0pt}{.5\pgfarrowwidth}%
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{\pgfarrowinset}{\ifpgfarrowharpoon-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth\else 0pt\fi}%
    % Adjust inset
    \pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{\pgfarrowinset}
    \advance\pgfarrowinset by\pgf@yc%
    % The following are needed in the code:
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfutil@tempdima
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfutil@tempdimb
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlinewidth
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgf@ya
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowinset
  },
  drawing code = {
    \pgfsetdash{{1pt}{1pt}}{0pt}
    \ifpgfarrowroundjoin\pgfsetroundjoin\else\pgfsetmiterjoin\fi
    \ifdim\pgfarrowlinewidth=\pgflinewidth\else\pgfsetlinewidth{+\pgfarrowlinewidth}\fi
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima\advance\pgf@x by\pgf@ya}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@ya}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfarrowinset}{0pt}}
    \ifpgfarrowharpoon \else
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@ya}{-\pgfutil@tempdimb}}
    \fi
    \pgfpathclose
    \ifpgfarrowopen\pgfusepathqstroke\else\ifdim\pgfarrowlinewidth>0pt\pgfusepathqfillstroke\else\pgfusepathqfill\fi\fi
  },
  parameters = {
    \the\pgfarrowlinewidth,%
    \the\pgfarrowlength,%
    \the\pgfarrowwidth,%
    \the\pgfarrowinset,%
    \ifpgfarrowharpoon h\fi%
    \ifpgfarrowopen o\fi%
    \ifpgfarrowroundjoin j\fi%
  },
}
\makeatother
\pgfkeys{
  Dashed Triangle /.tip      = {Dashed Stealth[inset=+0pt, angle=+60:+2.7pt +3.6]},
}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{dotArrow/.style={
  draw=blue, dotted, line width=0.6pt, double distance=4pt,
  {Bar[width=5.2pt]}-{Dashed Triangle[angle=90:7.2pt, fill=white]},
  postaction={draw=white, solid, line width=4pt, shorten >=4pt, shorten <=0.6pt, -}}
}  

\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=5pt]
  \node[draw] (node1) {Node 1};
  \node[draw, right=of node1] (node2) {Node 2};
  \draw[dotArrow] (node1) -- (node2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

unsure if I got the question correctly, I hope the following is helpful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{dotArrow} = [
  draw=draw, blue, dotted, single arrow,
  minimum height=10mm, minimum width=5mm,
  single arrow head extend=2mm]

\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=5pt]
\node[draw] (node1) {Node 1};
\node[draw, right=of node1] (node2) {Node 2};
\node[dotArrow] at (1.3, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This gives a nice looking arrow. But I think these kind of arrows don't allow for drawing between nodes at arbitrary places, e.g.,  using this syntax: `\draw (node1) -| (node2);`

Comment: @DavidPurton Of course, I always think of min. tweaks to achieve a reasonable result.